# Stretch side of half cylinder

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to pull the curved side of a half cylinder, so instead of doing this,
[image: example]

The curved side should bend to match where I am dragging the edge, while keeping the base in place (instead of pulling whole curved side, the curved side should bend to keep its position.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You can choose 3D cursor as pivot point and select everything and do s+z to scale on Z axis.

[image]
[image]

2 - You can use proportional editing, select the top edge and pull up. Adjust circle/influence size with mouse wheel.

[image]

[image]